# threads and high level languages

Tags: multithreading

can someone tell me why if i use threads it's better to use an low level languages like c++
and not c# and JAVA? someone asked me that in an interview and i did'nt know the answer

Comment: On what basis do you consider the interviewer to be correct?

Comment: I'd like to see some evidence of this. I don't believe it's necessarily true

Comment: because it was to the army and they know what they are talking about...

Comment: ** he told me it's connect somehow to the garbage collector

Comment: I would hesitate to assume that an interviewer in the army (and I don't know *which* army) will automatically know what he's talking about. From what you've said above, the question ties more to the impact of a garbage collector running in a separate thread, rather than threading *per se*.

Comment: Without any context, the statement is baseless.  I'll bet you discussed this in some illuminating context, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will you use threads or not - depends solely on application, not on language. And language is a function of design.
C++ provides more control, c# provides more abstraction, Java provides simplification, but in the end they all work the same way.

Answer (score 3):

It's news to me. Higher level languages provide easy to use abstractions over thread management, for example.

I expect the interviewer's point would make sense in context. It's dependent on the problem in hand - the level of timing control you need if you're writing a computer game or software for an engine management system may be greater than if you are writing a conference room booking system.

You trade off the low-level control and the associated learning curve and risk you get with lower-level languages for ease of use, safety and productivity of higher-level languages.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is necessarily true. In Java (I can't comment on C#) a thread maps directly to a native thread. From [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/thread-priorities.html#javabackground):

> The Java HotSpot™ virtual machine
>   currently associates each Java thread
>   with a unique native thread. The
>   relationship between the Java thread
>   and the native thread is stable and
>   persists for the lifetime of the Java
>   thread.

plus you have the additional high level constructs such as the [Executor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) framework.

Going forwards, functional languages (such as F# and Scala) encourage immutability, which contribute to a safer threaded environment.

There may well be scenarios where a low-level language offers more control (as for most requirements), but I suspect those will be fairly specialised situations. You have to balance that against the safety/productivity that the higher-level languages offer.

EDIT : From your comments supplementing the question, this *may* relate to running a garbage collector and consequent garbage-collection pauses and the impact on providing real-time performance and predictability. Threading in C/C++ may well offer some benefits in this area since a garbage collection cycle is not going to kick off during some critical time-dependent code. For this reason (amongst others) Java can't be considered as a real-time platform.

Answer (score 2):

like most answers : it depends.  languages  with built in threading facilities like C# and Java
will do some or most of the work  needed for thread usage and synchronization for you.

with C++ you have  do it yourself but you can employ better optimization techniques for your specific OS and platform